# Getting infinite loop because the number is too big to handle

Tags: javascript, algorithm

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/coding-interview-prep/project-euler/problem-5-smallest-multiple

I am solving Project Euler and this is the solution I came up with for the 5th question. It passes the first 5 test cases but fails at the last one. `smallestMult(20)`

I believe it is happening because the number gets too big when `n>=17`. (it is working in the codesnippet here without a problem)

```js
function smallestMult(n) {
  let num = n
  let count = n

  while(true){
    num = num + n
    for(let i = n; i>0; i--){
      if(num%i==0){
        count = count - 1
      }
      if(count==0){
        return num
      }
    }
    count = n
  }
}
console.log(smallestMult(20));
```

Any idea on how to improve?

Comment: This is basically a brute-force solution, you just try out every number until you find a high enough one. This will not end well. Instead you need to try to think about the factors that the output must have and why, this is basically a math exercise.

Comment: For me it passes the last test too in nodeJS, so it's something browser related or from the website itself, either way, your code is the brute-force solution but it works!

Comment: It takes too long to finish. These challenges are designed for you to come up with an efficient solution. Although in the first few exercises you might get it done with a rather brute force method, this will not work for all the other challenges.

Comment: I see. I guess I hit the barrier which stops me from brute forcing anymore. It was a fine ride till now. :)

Comment: Find prime numbers between 1 and n (inclusive), and find the largest power of each prime that's less than or equal to n. Multiply all these together for the answer. For n=20, that's 2⁴ * 3² * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19. You can actually solve this question with paper and pen for n reasonably large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works however is less efficient. You can try this method:

```js
function smallestMult(n) {
  let index = 1;
  let lcm= 1;
  // Loop until the last number
  while(index != n+1){
    // Get lcm of index and previous lcm
    lcm = findLcm(lcm,index)
    // Increment Index
    index++
  }
  return lcm
}

function findLcm(n1,n2){
let hcf;
// looping from 1 to number1 and number2 to find HCF
for (let i = 1; i <= n1 && i <= n2; i++) {
    // check if is factor of both integers
    if( n1 % i == 0 && n2 % i == 0) {
        hcf = i;
    }
}
// find LCM
let lcm = (n1 * n2) / hcf;
return lcm
}

console.log(smallestMult(24))
console.log(smallestMult(17))
console.log(smallestMult(29))
```

Comment: Amazing. Works so fast. I need to study your code for a while.

Comment: @Noexceptions `lcm` (least common multiple) and `gcd` (greatest common divisor) are some basic algorithms you **need** to know and understand by heart. The entire exercise is just a big lcm over and over again.